# Problem with "Equivalent To" and data properties in Protege

Tags: owl, ontology, protege

I am trying to add to "Equivalent To"

```
Patient and (hasSmokerStatus some xsd:boolean [= "true"])
```

however I cannot add it as I got error in `xsd:boolean`.

I tried

```
Patient and (hasSmokerStatus some xsd:boolean ["true"])
```

I tried all that with and without quotes, as well as

```
Patient and (hasSmokerStatus some "true"^^xsd:boolean)
```

but nothing works.

How can I use boolean in the "Equivalent To"?

Answer (score 2):

Your idea is to adapt datatype restrictions ([7.5](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Datatype_Restrictions)) to boolean values. However, no constraining facet is normative for this datatype ([4.4](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Boolean_Values)). Instead, you need enumerations of literals
([7.4](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Enumeration_of_Literals)). In Protégé:

```
Patient that hasSmokerStatus some {true}
```

Data property existential restrictions ([8.4.2](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Existential_Quantification_2)) with single-value data ranges could be replaced with literal value restrictions ([8.4.3](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Literal_Value_Restriction)). In Protégé:

```
Patient that hasSmokerStatus value true
```

Comment: unfortunately, these solution do not works too, the first one said it expected or and, the second one said it expected individual name

Comment: @FatimahAltuhaifa, perhaps you created `hasSmokerStatus` as an object property, not as a data property. Which Protege version are you using, by the way?

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped, actually I have it as object properties, and data properties, after removing the object properties, it works as you say. thanks